# What are the criteria for migrating a question to the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have found a few questions that look like they should belong in the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange.  What should Ask Ubuntu questions involve that sets them apart from the ones in Unix/Linux SE?

Comment: Why not link to the questions? But basically, usually questions about unofficial derivatives can be migrated over.

Comment: In such cases, if I know the answer, I generally answer it in short such that the person gets rid of the problem and provide links for further reading, explanation, and appropriate fora.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that makes is an unofficial derivative is a candidate.

Anything that doesn't directly relate to Ubuntu or use on Ubuntu is a candidate.

It's CW so feel free to add candidate indicators.

Comment: What about questions that involve a low-level part of Ubuntu, or a GTK programming question?  How technically deep is "too much"?

Comment: That's a soft limit.  If it get's answered here, great.  Generally, the idea is: put it where it gets fixed and cross-link it if required

Comment: What about the common rule observed, reading as "Don't migrate crap?" What would be the cutoff for a question's quality?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ of course.  I thought we were addressing indicators, not copy pasting the FAQ.